# can't boot freeze at login

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, xserver

I am trying login and my system just freezes.

I was messing around with my Catalyst driver trying to get my dual 7950s into crossfire mode and it would work..so in my terminal I typed startx and then it locked up.  I rebooted my system and now it is frozen after login.

How can I repair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

When typing startx it creates a .dbus file in the users home directory with root permissions.

I simply

```
sudo mv .dbus bak.dbus
```

after that I was able to login.